# How can I make xfce4-terminal start fish shell?

Tags: shell, fish, xfce4-terminal

I want to use FISH shell. But I've read FISH is not a POSIX shell so setting it to default shell by `chsh` is not recommended. What I want is whenever I start xfce4-terminal I would like to start FISH shell instead of bash. Adding `exec fish` to `.bashrc` seems to be a solution, but I want a to know if there is a way to start fish without starting it on top of bash.

Comment: Do you use `xfce4-terminal` for some things and have terminals some other way, where you want `fish` for `xfce4-terminal` and bash for everything else?  If you're going to always use `xfce4-terminal`, then I why not `chsh`?

Comment: Using fish shell as default might cause some crach according to @Naheel https://askubuntu.com/questions/26439/how-do-i-set-fish-as-the-default-shell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, sure. Run:

```
xfce4-terminal --preferences
```

And make: `Run a custom command instead of my shell` and type `fish` in the box just below. That's it, close and start `xfc4-terminal`. That's it. Enjoy.